# How to use kubectl from a CronJob in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed a CronJob in a GKE cluster to periodically replicate secrets in namespaces (for `cert-manager`), but I always get the following error:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Here is my deployment:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: certificate-replicator-cron-job
  namespace: default
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: default
            release: default
        spec:
          automountServiceAccountToken: false
          containers:
          - command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - for i in $(kubectl get ns -o json |jq -r ".items[].metadata.name" |grep
              "^bf-"); do kubectl get secret -o json --namespace default dev.botfront.cloud-staging-tls
              --export |jq 'del(.metadata.namespace)' |kubectl apply -n ${i}-f -;  done
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            name: certificate-replicator-container
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          serviceAccountName: sa-certificate-replicator
  schedule: '* * * * *'
```

I also set up a role for the service account:

```sh
$ kubectl describe role certificate-replicator-role                                                                                                                                 
Name:         certificate-replicator-role
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources   Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------   -----------------  --------------  -----
  secrets     []                 []              [list create get]
  namespaces  []                 []              [list get]
```

```sh
$ kubectl describe rolebinding certificate-replicator-role-binding                                                                                                                  git:(master|✚4…
Name:         certificate-replicator-role-binding
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  Role
  Name:  certificate-replicator-role
Subjects:
  Kind            Name                       Namespace
  ----            ----                       ---------
  ServiceAccount  sa-certificate-replicator  default
```

```sh
$ kubectl describe serviceaccount sa-certificate-replicator                                                                                                                         git:(master|✚4…
Name:                sa-certificate-replicator
Namespace:           default
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   sa-certificate-replicator-token-ljsfb
Tokens:              sa-certificate-replicator-token-ljsfb
Events:              <none>
```

I understand that I could probably create another Docker image with `gcloud` preinstalled and authenticate with a service account key, but I'd like to be cloud provider agnostic and also avoid having to authenticate to the cluster since `kubectl` is being invoked from inside.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Gcloud demands that you authenticate in some way. I used a .json file to authenticate a google-cloud's service account every time I wanted to run a kubectl remotely. However, this is a pretty dirty solution.

Instead, I would recomment to use kubernetes api to achieve your goal. Create a role that allows you to operate on namespaces and configmaps resources. Associate it with a service account and then make curls to make the copy from inside the cronjob.

Here is an example for the default namespace.

First create a role and associate it with your service account (default in this example).

```
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: nssc-clusterrole
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["namespaces", "configmaps", "secrets"]
  verbs: ["*"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nssc-clusterrolebinding
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  name: nssc-clusterrole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
subjects:
  - name: default
    namespace: default
    kind: ServiceAccount
```

Second, create a secret to test.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secrets-test
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
stringData:
  mysecret1: abc123
  mysecret2: def456
```

Third, make a curl request to get your secret.

```sh
curl --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernet
es.io/serviceaccount/token)" -H "Accept: application/json"  https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/sec
rets-test
```

You will get a json with the content of your secret.

```
{
  "kind": "Secret",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "secrets-test",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/secrets-test",
    "uid": "...",
    "resourceVersion": "...",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-10-26T01:52:29Z",
    "annotations": {
      "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "{...}\n"
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "mysecret1": "base64value",
    "mysecret2": "base64value"
  },
  "type": "Opaque"
}
```

Fourth, create the secret in a new namespace by changing the json and making a new curl request. Also associate the service account with the role.

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nssc-clusterrolebinding
  namespace: new-namespace
roleRef:
  name: nssc-handler-clusterrole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
subjects:
  - name: default
    namespace: default
    kind: ServiceAccount
```

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "mysecret1": "Y29udHJvbDEyMyE=",
        "mysecret2": "Y29udHJvbDQ1NiE="
    },
    "kind": "Secret",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "secrets-test",
        "namespace": "new-namespace"
    },
    "type": "Opaque"
}
```

```sh
curl -X POST -d @test.json --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /va
r/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://kub
ernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/new-namespace/secrets
```

Comment: Thank you @Rodrigo Loza but I'd really prefer to use kubectl. Besides kubectl wraps the API, so it shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: Kind of. Kubectl uses a Go implementation wrapper of k8s API. If you want to use kubectl it is way easier then, just copy the .kube folder into the root of your pod and run kubectl. Just saying, it is not an elegant solution and pretty much insecure. You think you can upvote the answer? Thanks