# Run kubectl command from GKE cronjob using workload identity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'd like to run a kubectl command from within a `cronjob` pod, to change the min replicas on a HPA for a deployment at the same time every week, i.e. time based scaling. I've been playing around with using the official google-sdk image with gcloud and kubectl installed.

I know I need to authenticate to the GKE cluster before I can run commands to interact via kubectl, and I really wanted to steer away from mounting a service account key (via a secret) to the pod, as we already have workload identity enabled.

Normal gcloud commands work fine using this method e.g. `gcloud compute instances list` but when I run `gcloud container clusters get-credentials....` it fails saying I need to run `gcloud auth login` - can't be done of course.

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58566634/how-to-use-kubectl-from-a-cronjob-in-gke), I don't really want to use cURL if I can avoid it,  and also know that gcloud doesn't use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67394633/how-to-use-gcloud-command-in-docker-build-image-with-credentials))

Does anyone know of a way I can use workload identity and get this working?

Comment: Are you running the commend from a pod or a node?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm running it from within the pod. I think I might have found a way/reason why it wasn't working. If I run the gcloud command with `gcloud --account....` it seems to authenticate to the cluster fine.

Comment: Interesting. Auto-answer your question, it could help many people (me included!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get this authenticated, I had to use the following command before I tried to run kubectl commands from within the cronjob pod:

`gcloud --account <account-name>`